# Notation in LTC constant rate distance and locality

Tags: notation

In the article "LTC constant rate distance and locality" (link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.04808.pdf), right after Lemma 2.1, the writer define the next:

> Let $D$ be any probability distribution over a finite set $V$, and define an inner product by:
> $$\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle_D :\mathbb{R}^V \times \mathbb{R}^V \mapsto \mathbb{R}\quad\text{by}\quad\langle f,f'\rangle_D =\mathbb{E}_{x \sim D}(f(x)f'(x))$$

Now, I'm not sure about the meaning of the word distribution here, but the author gives the next example: Given a subset of $V$, say $T\subset V$, and denote $\mathbb{1}_T$ the indicator function over $T$, then $\langle 1_T,1_T\rangle= \mathbb{P}_D(T)$.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: What do you want to know about it? It is pretty straightforward really, it is basically the same as the covariance except without subtracting off the means.

Comment: The distribution suppose to be derived from some r.v . Who are these x~D that we are having?

Comment: $x \sim D$ just means that the $x$ inside the expectation is drawn from the distribution $D$ on $V$.

Comment: I see. So how do you choose which element of the distribution your'e considering? Like in the example of the indicator of a set, one can take disjoint set to T which is measurable, and the function over this set (from the distribution) is 0.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the syntax. To be explicit, for a discrete distribution, $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim D}[g(x)]=\sum_{y \in V} g(y) p(y)$, where $p$ is the probability mass function of the distribution $D$. So in the symbol $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim D}[g(x)]$, $x$ is a bound variable, it doesn't take any particular value.

Comment: Thank you so much!